# Is Clojure Avout functionally equivalent to the operational transformation features in Google Wave?

Tags: clojure, google-sheets, operational-transform

In this [Google Groups message](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/clojure/rJlNqJ2JRME/QQTnZuMhp08J) - the author compares the Clojure library named Avout to the Operational Transform features in Google Wave.

Is it fair to say that these are functionally equivalent?

I understand that the operational tranform functionality was then used in Google Spreadsheets to enable the multi-user functionality we see there today.

Could you use Clojure Avout as part of an online spreadsheet implementation to synchronise state between users and resolve conflicts (in sequence)? (ie if the first user adds a character to a cell shortly in time before the other user deletes the entire contents of the cell - would it amically be able to resolve the conflict with the later update - deleting the cell?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Avout but [operational transform isn't very complicated](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation), I've implemented it myself many years ago.

Comment: Is your implementation available publicly?